# Find non-duplicate objects that meet certain conditions

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

I have this db structure...

```
{
_id: int
A1: string
A2: [{
    _id: int
    B1: [int]
    B2: int
    B3: string
    B4: string
    B5: [{
        C1: string
        C2: {D1: string}
    }]
    B6: string
    B7: false
}]
}
```

And the data is in this way.

```
{_id:1, A1: "A", A2[{_id: 1, B1:[1], B2:1, B3:"X", B4:"B", B5[{C1:"123", C2:{D1: "331"}}], B6:"Ex", B7:true}]}
{_id:1, A1: "A", A2[{_id: 2, B1:[1], B2:1, B3:"Y", B4:"U", B5[{C1:"456", C2:{D1: "332"}}], B6:"Ea", B7:false}]}
{_id:2, A1: "Z", A2[{_id: 3, B1:[1], B2:2, B3:"I", B4:"O", B5[{C1:"789", C2:{D1: "333"}}], B6:"Eq", B7:false}]}
{_id:2, A1: "Z", A2[{_id: 4, B1:[1], B2:2, B3:"P", B4:"L", B5[{C1:"123", C2:{D1: "334"}}], 6:"Ee", B7:true}]}
```

So I want to pull the data like this.

```
{_id:1, A1: "A", A2[{_id: 1, B1:[1], B2:1, B3:"X", B4:"B", B5[{C1:"123", C2:{D1: "331"}}], B6:"Ex", B7:true}]}
{_id:1, A1: "A", A2[{_id: 2, B1:[1], B2:1, B3:"Y", B4:"U", B5[{C1:"456", C2:{D1: "332"}}], B6:"Ea", B7:false}]}
{_id:2, A1: "Z", A2[{_id: 3, B1:[1], B2:2, B3:"I", B4:"O", B5[{C1:"789", C2:{D1: "333"}}], B6:"Eq", B7:false}]}
```

In other words, I want to check if the value of C1 is duplicated among the documents in the array of A2 and get the remaining documents except the duplicate value in the A2 array.

Comment: Is sample given in question taken from mid of any aggregation ? If not how do you've have same `_id`'s from multiple docs ?? Is that a typo ?

Comment: @whoami There is no typo.
I find all the objects in the A2 array, but if there is a duplicate of C2, I want to bring only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the query for this

```
//Populate the data
db.sample.insert({_id:1, A1: "A", A2:[{_id: 1, B1:[1], B2:1, B3:"X", B4:"B", B5:[{C1:"123", C2:{D1: "331"}}], B6:"Ex", B7:true}]})
db.sample.insert({_id:2, A1: "A", A2:[{_id: 2, B1:[1], B2:1, B3:"Y", B4:"U", B5:[{C1:"456", C2:{D1: "332"}}], B6:"Ea", B7:false}]})
db.sample.insert({_id:3, A1: "Z", A2:[{_id: 3, B1:[1], B2:2, B3:"I", B4:"O", B5:[{C1:"789", C2:{D1: "333"}}], B6:"Eq", B7:false}]})
db.sample.insert({_id:4, A1: "Z", A2:[{_id: 4, B1:[1], B2:2, B3:"P", B4:"L", B5:[{C1:"123", C2:{D1: "334"}}], 6:"Ee", B7:true}]})

db.sample.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:'$A2.B5.C1',docs:{$addToSet:'$$CURRENT'}}},//here we have grouped using the C1 field
{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:{$arrayElemAt:['$docs',0]}}}//as you need only the first doc, arrayElemAt is used to take first doc and replaced to root
])
```